# Angular / TypeScript - Call a function after another one has been completed

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I would like to call `f2` after `f1` has been completed. `f1` function can be **synchronous** or **asynchronous**. I need an example that work in both cases. I have found a solution, using a `Promise` and a timer:

```
global() {
    this.f1().then(res => {
        this.f2()
    })
}

f1() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {

        // Some code...

        setTimeout( () => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 1500);
    });
}

f2() {
    // Some code...
}
```

The problem is the program always have to wait **1500ms**. I don't want `f2` start before `f1` is finished.
Is there a way to wait the time needed, not more or less?

Comment: What about `f2(); f1();`

Comment: Why are you waiting 1500ms until running `f2`? If at any point in the future it took longer to retrieve the data for `f1` to complete, your code would break.

Comment: You need to expand your question to say what else is happening in `f1`, if it were only the code with your timeout then you could safely delete it. If it is some call to retrieve remote data then that call will be returning a promise so that is the promise you must return from `f1` and then `f2` will run as soon as the data has returned.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So remove the `setTimeout` part. It will call `resolve` or `reject` and then pass the execution to the next `then` or `catch` handler. If you have some asynchronous call in the Promise, you need to call `resolve/reject` in the result of that call.

What about not waiting `1500ms` - the given time is actually the lowest time after which the function may be called. Maybe after `2000ms` This is related to the main thread in which JS code works. If main thread has no work to done, then the results of the asynchronous calls are going to be executed.

```js
function f1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('f1');
        resolve();
    });
}

function f2() {
   console.log('f2');
}

f1().then(res => f2());
```

Comment: can we use the same way for events calling  also in angular?

Answer (score 12):

> If `f1` is **synchronous**, there is nothing special to do:

```
global() {
    f1();
    f2();
}
```

> If `f1` is **asynchronous** and return an *Observable*, use `Rxjs
>   operator`, like [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html):

```
global() {
    f1().concatMap(() => f2());
}
```

> If `f1` is **asynchronous** and return a *Promise*, use `async/await`:

```
async global() {
    await f1();
    f2();
}
```

> If `f1` is **asynchronous** and return a *Promise* (alternative):

```
global() {
    f1().then(res => f2());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the timeout

```
function f1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('i am first');
        resolve();
    });
}

function f2() {
    console.log('i am second');
}

f1().then(f2);
```

Comment: If you're using Observables use switchMap to make a request first and then other one or forkJoin if you  make requests in parallel