# Angular 8: Run Component Class Methods Synchronously/Sequentially

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

How do I run methods synchronously in Angular Typescript?
These are not functions, but methods.
First one calls a service, and then second saves into an array.

```
runTwoMethods()
{
  this.validateAddress();
  this.saveJsonArchive();
}
```

Validate address may call more sub-method,may not even be Api, so want to wait until everything completes before saving.

Following syntax is for functions, currently searching for class methods,

[Angular / TypeScript - Call a function after another one has been completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538814/angular-typescript-call-a-function-after-another-one-has-been-completed)

At the end, data is stored into a current data object. And I want to be 
save to an archive. Maybe another possibility, how do I keep AddressCurrentMailing and JSONArchive[2] in sync?

Current Data object is sourced from API, not sure where (nor I am not allowed to edit the APIs, then calls transformations), and then would like to save into JsonArchive.

```
 this.jsonArchive[this.jsonArchiveCounter] = this.addressCurrentMailingFinalData
```

Comment: What does `validateAddress` return?

Comment: hi @PierreDuc it call some services, but is a void method, nothing

Comment: Then it's not (entirely) possible, you should return either a promise or an observable from that method, to be able to async call the next one

Comment: I just wrote end goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Observable` for the 1st and use your 2nd method after `Subscribe` in callback:

```
validateAddress(): Observable<Someclassname>
{
    return this._http.get<Someclassname>('url');
}

this.yourService.validateAddress().subscribe(
                (result) => { 
                  this.saveJsonArchive();
                },
                (error) => console.log('NO saveJsonArchive'));
```

**EDIT** (`validateAddress` with more one `Observable`)

```
const ox: Observable<Someclassname>[] = [];
ox.push(this.http.get<Someclassname>(url1));
ox.push(this.http.get<Someclassname>(url2));
ox.push(this.http.get<Someclassname>(url3));
forkJoin(ox).subscribe(result => this.saveJsonArchive());
```

Comment: can you generalize it more? this validate address may call more sub methods and may not even be an api, so I want to wait untill everything is done before saving then run thanks

Comment: @SailorLuvBoat You need to use rxjs functions so that everything inside `validateAddress()` gets encapsulated into an observable. We could help you with that if you showed what code you have in `validateAddress()`

Comment: in `validateAddress` you can have more one `Observable` and run all in // and after you do un `forkJoin`.

Answer (score -1):

You could return a Promise in "this.validateAddress();" and await it.

I assume you use the Angular HttpClient.

For example:

```
private validateAddress(): Promise<someclassname>
{
    return this._http.get<someclassname>("someurl").toPromise()
}


async addSeasonal()
{
    await this.validateAddress();
    await this.saveJsonArchive();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can you generalize it more?  this validate address may call more sub methods and may not even be an api, so I want to wait untill everything is done before saving then run

Comment: also, why do I have to edit the sub methods? can I just do Promise in the combined method, on each of the sub methods?

Comment: Every method runs synchronously by default. The difference is that http calls with the httpClient don't run synchronously. They return an observable. The easiest way is to turn that into a promise as described and await it (or give it a callback with a `.then((returnValue) => {})`.

Comment: validate address, does not actually call the api, its lot of other methods within it which do

Comment: Converting observables to promises is an antipattern. Just return the observable and pipe into `forkJoin`/`switchMap`/`map`/whatever