# How to execute 2 function after one another in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am calling following two functions:

```
getStudentDataFunction(){
........
return studentData
}

getTeachersDataFunction(){
........
return teachersData
}
```

I want the getTeachersDataFunction() to be executed after
getStudentDataFunction() completes returning data.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may refer to this similar issue: [Angular / TypeScript - Call a function after another one has been completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538814/angular-typescript-call-a-function-after-another-one-has-been-completed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Synchronous and asynchronous execution

If the functions are synchronous, you can just call them sequentially because they are executed one after another:

```
getStudentDataFunction()
getTeachersDataFunction()
```

However presumably the functions are asynchronous, otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question. That means one statement in that function must start the process of obtaining data, but it is obtained via another program path.

#### Example of an asynchronous request

One example of this would be [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the standard way of making an in-browser HTTP request (the example is from [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)):

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

Here the `oReq.send();` makes the HTTP request, starting the process of requesting data. But the way that data is actually obtained is via the use of the callback function `reqListener` in the second line. When the data is ready, that function is separately called with a `this` context object which allows the HTTP response to be obtained. So any code to be executed as a result of the HTTP request returning must be called from `reqListener`.

#### Applying to your scenario

In order to get your functions to operate sequentially, you need to identify the the callback function or other mechanism `getStudentDataFunction()` uses to obtain its data, and then use one of JavaScript's ways of handling asynchronous code to order the functions in the way you want. The three main ways are callbacks, [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (from oldest to most modern). `getStudentDataFunction()` should itself be using one of those three methods.

These would work as follows:

```
// 1. If getStudentDataFunction() accepts a callback

var studentCallback = function(studentData) {
   getTeachersDataFunction()
}
getStudentDataFunction(studentCallback)

// 2. If getStudentDataFunction() returns a Promise:

getStudentDataFunction()
   .then(getTeachersDataFunction) // second function is only called when Promise resolves

// 3. If getStudentDataFunction() returns a Promise and you wish to use async functions:

async function getAllData() {
   await getStudentDataFunction() // await keyword makes execution wait for Promise to resolve
   getTeachersDataFunction()
}

getAllData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make this two method Observable with Rxjs, thus you can do something like this:

```
  caller() {
    this.method1()
      .pipe(switchMap(res1 => this.method2(res1)))
      .subscribe(res2 => {
        console.log(res2);
      });
  }
```

Also see the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rn5kfe?file=src/app/app.component.ts